# How to remove all rows in dataframe according to the time

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column `dt` that has `dtype=datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]`. I'd like to remove all the rows who's `datetime.time` is `16:00:00-05:00`. How can I do this in a vectorized fashion?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example input?

Comment: *16:00:00-05:00*. Do you mean you want to remove all rows between 16:00 and 05:00 or -05:00 is the US/Eeastern timezone (without DST)?

Answer (score 1):

**Examle**

```
i = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=4, freq='1D20H30min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=i)
```

`df`

```
                    A
2018-04-09 00:00:00 1
2018-04-10 20:30:00 2
2018-04-12 17:00:00 3
2018-04-14 13:30:00 4
```

**Code**

use `between_time`

```
df.between_time('05:00', '16:00')
```

output:

```
                    A
2018-04-14 13:30:00 4
```

Comment: The OP said *I have a dataframe with a column dt*. `between_time` is only available if you have a `DatetimeIndex` as index.

Comment: That's right. But it's not difficult to make

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time` module:

```
import time

# To remove 16:00:00
out = df[df['dt'].dt.time != time(16)]

# To remove between 16:00:00 and 16:05:00
out = df[~df['dt'].dt.time.between(time(16), time(16, 5))]
```